# Logging in using SSH keys

Tags: ssh, redhat, ssh-keys

I created a non-root user, new_user, on a Red Hat Linux machine.
I then logged in as new_user and created a private/public key pair.

I've created /home/new_user/.ssh, and I've appended the public key to the authorized_keys file, but I'm not able to log in using the key pair.  For instance, if I execute the command

```
ssh -i /home/new_user/privatekey new_user@localhost
```

I get prompted for a password.

Comment: Can you provide debugging output?  That is, can you paste the output of `ssh -v -i /home/new_user/privatekey new_user@localhost`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ssh-copy-id` command to automate the task of setting up key pairs.

Answer (score 1):

This is the formula for the right permissions on the server side.

```
chmod go-w ~/
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

You can also use the `ssh-copy-id` script (available on EL5 and EL6) to copy a key from your system to the remote system. It corrects the permissions to enable remote connections to work.